# Is there an alternative interface for viewing a twitter tweet/thread that has lots of replies from different people?

Tags: twitter

If a tweet/thread has over 1000 replies, the desktop website isn't optimal or practical for reading the various replies.

Answer (score 0):

Try expanding the window across two monitors. However there isn't a default method for what you're asking for. You could try to look for some third party software, or make your own, however I don't know if Twitter allows this.

Comment: Expanding the web browser window across two monitors wouldn't work because all the replies to the thread appear in a fluid width column in rows of one, so it doesn't really expand in size by displaying more posts on the screen with a larger screen width.